# How I can write on the variable ExpectedHttpStatusCode

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I need to write to a variable value ExpectedHttpStatusCode.

I came to this conclusion, but I do not know what to do next?

```bsh
$new = Get-AzResource -ResourceId /subscriptions/<subscriptions>/resourceGroups/us-test-vitalii/providers/microsoft.insights/webtests/us-test-vitalii-ui
$new.Properties.Configuration.WebTest 




<WebTest         Name="us-test-vitalii-ui"         Id=""         Enabled="True"
         CssProjectStructure=""         CssIteration=""         Timeout="120"         WorkItemIds=""         xmlns="http://mi
crosoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010"         Description=""         CredentialUserName=""         CredentialPasswo
rd=""         PreAuthenticate="True"         Proxy="default"         StopOnError="False"         RecordedResultFile=""       
  ResultsLocale="">        <Items>        <Request         Method="GET"         Guid=""  
       Version="1.1"         Url=""         ThinkTime="0"         Timeo
ut="120"         ParseDependentRequests="True"         FollowRedirects="True"         RecordResult="True"         Cache="Fals
e"         ResponseTimeGoal="0"         Encoding="utf-8"         ExpectedHttpStatusCode="350"         ExpectedResponseUrl="" 
        ReportingName=""         IgnoreHttpStatusCode="False" />        </Items>        <ValidationRules>        <ValidationR
ule         Classname="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.Rules.ValidationRuleFindText, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Quali
tyTools.WebTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"         DisplayName="Find Text"
         Description="Verifies the existence of the specified text in the response."         Level="High"         ExectuionOr
der="BeforeDependents">        <RuleParameters>        <RuleParameter Name="FindText" Value="us-test-vitalii-ui" />
        <RuleParameter Name="IgnoreCase" Value="False" />        <RuleParameter Name="UseRegularExpression" Value="False" /> 
       <RuleParameter Name="PassIfTextFound" Value="True" />        </RuleParameters>        </ValidationRule>        </Valid
ationRules>        </WebTest>
```

Comment: Suppose you change that value, then what will you do with it? Are you asking just for a way to change the value or to change the value AND upload it back into Azure?

Comment: This xml seems broken. In theory, you should be able to use XPath to drill down to that attribute or cast the output to [xml] and traverse the object properties. With the XML in the shape that it is in, you will need to replace text. If we assume `$variableValue` has a status code, then you can use `$new.Properties.Configuration.WebTest -replace '(?<=ExpectedHttpStatusCode=")\d+',$variableValue`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, the XML seems broken. If you want to write to `ExpectedHttpStatusCode`, you could consider using the REST API [Web Tests - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/webtests/createorupdate), update the [`properties.Configuration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/webtests/createorupdate#configuration). To call the API in PowerShell, you could use [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6). For more details about call rest api with powershell, you could see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55953041/how-can-i-query-azure-status-using-powershell/55962252#55962252), it's similar.

For the access token of the api, you could click the `Try it` button, login and copy the `Authorization` as below. Or if you want to generate manually, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#acquire-an-access-token).

[image]