# Is there a health REST API to check status (Up or down ) for Microsoft Azure embeddded Power BI service urls(https://api.powerbi.com/)?

Tags: angular, azure, rest, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm embedding Power BI reports in angular, I want to check status of MS azure power BI embedded URLs.
Is there any REST API i can use to check status if service is down, up or outage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the service health of all Azure Resources using the below :

```
$url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION>/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses?api-version=2015-01-01"
$accesstoken = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV...........9_pD8hhLrYeWMQD3Ihga33MAHTX-WzkrqcroBYkPx590cSxr6ghqdjYH131zt33eCfASBijMTe4gLxP16EBbkMo2vS4h2bg9rE-_OzQ
"

$header = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $accesstoken
}
$a = Invoke-RestMethod –Uri $url2 –Headers $header –Method GET
```

And filter for the POWERBI Embed or any azure resource you are looking for.

```
$a.value |?{$_.id -like "*power*"}
```

**Sample output :**

[image]

If you resource path for the PowerBI Embedded Resource you could use the below endpoint

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION>/resourcegroups/<RESOURCEGROUP>/providers/microsoft.powerbidedicated/capacities/<NAME>/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses/current?api-version=2015-01-01
```

Alternatively,

You could use a JS to scrape the information from https://azurestatuscdn.azureedge.net/en-us/status/feed/ on the outage.

Sample implementation is done https://github.com/snobu/azure-ticker

Also detailed in the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55966450/13755246

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that the above REST Endpoint and not a powershell script. I have used the Powershell inorder to invoke the REST Endpoint :)

Comment: Thank you Satya, I read more about azure resource management api documentation, it will solve my problem.

Comment: @veereshpatil, please consider accepting it as solution if it had helped :)