# Azure Status RSS Feed Example

Tags: azure, rss, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to setup downstream application which will get updates(Azure ADB2C Service Outage alerts only) from Azure Status RSS feed, filter the updates and will send filtered alerts/notifications to external application dashboard
I am planning to use the below RSS feed

- https://azurestatuscdn.azureedge.net/en-us/status/feed/

For this I need

- Sample/Example RSS feed having some data about some Azure Service Outage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55966450/8357357

Comment: Thanks Jas, the link is helpful